# Inconsistent JWT token payload with Firebase Authentication

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Authenticating a user using Firebase Web SDK 4.2.0 gives two different payloads inside JWT token. Sometimes it contains this:

```
{
  "azp": "...",
  "aud": "...",
  "sub": "...",
  "email": "...",
  "email_verified": true,
  "at_hash": "...",
  "iss": "accounts.google.com",
  "iat": 1502712944,
  "exp": 1502716544
}
```

and other times:

```
{
  "iss": "https://securetoken.google.com/{FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID}",
  "name": "...",
  "picture": "...",
  "aud": "...",
  "auth_time": 1502642892,
  "user_id": "...",
  "sub": "...",
  "iat": 1502711791,
  "exp": 1502715391,
  "email": "...",
  "email_verified": true,
  "firebase": {
    "identities": {
      "google.com": [
        "{GOOGLE_USER_ID}"
      ],
      "email": [
        "..."
      ]
    },
    "sign_in_provider": "google.com"
  }
}
```

What is going on here? Since I'm doing server-side validation (in Go, not using Admin SDK), it would be helpful if responses had a consistent format.

Answer (score 0):

The first token is a Google ID token. The second one is a Firebase ID token. You can tell from the issuer (iss). You appear to be sending the Google ID token to your server in some cases and the Firebase ID token in others.

Comment: This is happening without changing authentication code, though. I guess I have to handle each case separately on the server.